# Is the execution of a circuit neglectable for large optimization problems?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, optimization

Assume a large combinatorial optimization problem should be solved (e.g. via Grover) and further assume there is a (near error free) universal quantum computer with a sufficient number of qubits (and sufficiently good quantum volume/clops/gate fidelity): is the wall clock time of the circuit execution neglectable (in comparison to a classical exhaustive search or branch&bound)?

For instance, is it ok to assume that the execution of such a circuit for a TSP with thousands of cities only takes milliseconds or seconds? And even if thousands of shots are required, this would be faster by magnitudes than classical approaches.

So is it correct that once a (near perfect) quantum computer is available classical approaches can be easily beaten?